# Can I expand $(A∩B)∪(C∩D)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can I expand 
$$(A∩B)∪(C∩D)$$

just like I would do with multiplication/addition using the distributive law. I mean can I write this as:

$$(A∪C)∩(A∪D)∩(B∪C)∩(B∪D)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can. It's directly going from $$(A \cap B)\cup (C\cap D) \;\text{to } \;(A∪C)∩(A∪D)∩(B∪C)∩(B∪D)$$

rather than using the more belabored "middle step" in $$\begin{align} (A\cap B)\cup (C\cap D) & =[(A\cap B)\cup C]\cap [(A \cap B) \cup D]\\ \\ & = \;(A∪C)∩(A∪D)∩(B∪C)∩(B∪D)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well the steps need to be properly outlined if you ask me. Using the [distributive law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets) we have that

$$(A\cap B) \cup (C \cap D) = ((A\cap B)\cup C) \cap ((A\cap B)\cup D) $$ $$ = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (A \cup D) \cap (B \cup D)  $$